# cant make a open graph request on yammer opengraph ({"errors":["Missing required param \"activity\""]})

Tags: yammer

I am reading https://developer.yammer.com/opengraph/ . and trying to create my on app. I tried to make a simple opengraph request on php O got this error `({"errors":["Missing required param \"activity\""]})`.

here is my code

```
<?php


$data_string='{
"activity":{
"actor":{"name":"Sidd Singh",
"email":"adriantest@protonmail.ch},
"action":"created",
"object": {
"url":"https://www.sched.do",
"title":"Lunch Meeting"
}
}
}';
$access_token = '4Mheyevf4FmzRPtwNUviOQ'; 
$ch = curl_init('https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/activity.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: You should remove your OAUTH token from this post. And it's possible the endpoint you want to reach is https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/streams/activities.json

Comment: that is expired token :) so i will need to change the https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/activity.json to yammer.com/api/v1/streams/activities.json ??

Comment: hi @michaelh when i tried that i got                                               "The 'type' property must be one of 'text', 'status', 'created', 'changed', 'deleted', 'added', or 'updated'."

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about the endpoint, sorry to steer you in the wrong direction.